# Windows 10 BSOD screenshot: what is the next step?

Tags: windows

I have i9-12900k, Windows 10, Asus ROG STRIX Z690, and MSI GeForce RTX 2080. I have BSOD at as shown below. What will be the next step?

[image]

Comment: 1. Restart and see if you can start in Safe Mode. Try Shift and Restart.  2. Run the manufacturer's Hardware App to test hardware.

Comment: Thx. "Run the manufacturer's Hardware App to test hardware" How?

Comment: Go to the manufacturer's website and they (ASUS) should have a hardware test app.

Comment: I built this box at a shop.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045716/ This one?

Comment: Yes, follow through the article and see if it can help you.  I have seen this screen for both hardware errors and for operating system damage requiring removal of the disk to salvage data and then reinstall Windows.

Comment: Let me work on it

Comment: But where can one download the above asus software?

Comment: Try this:    https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1045716/   It tells you how to run the hardware diagnostics.

Comment: There will be a crash dump log, you would need to debug the log to find the real cause.

Comment: So the artifacts is an indication you have some serious cooling issues and either the GPU is crashing in such a way that the Windows kernel wasn’t able to recover or the CPU itself is to blame.  You should take whatever the shop built, to an entirely different shop, and allow them to build it properly

Comment: the question is "where can one download this ASUS software?"

Comment: Here:    https://asus-pc-diagnostics.en.lo4d.com/windows

Comment: I got https://imgur.com/a/OvYMrnw and https://imgur.com/a/2oQf3Z8

Comment: Thus seems to me that the Video card is alive?

Comment: "ASUS Software" is unlikley to help you but I guess it *might*.  How many times did this happen?  You never mentioned it.

Comment: every time I turn on this PC.

Comment: "There will be a crash dump log, you would need to debug the log to find the real cause." Where can I find one?

Comment: Here is the dmp files https://files.catbox.moe/humviv.zip